# gruntjs-SBT run portXX - Scala on Intellij Windows

Tags: gruntjs

Can anyone help on issue below?

Not able to SBT run portXX using Scala on Windows

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grunt" (in directory "C:\Prashan
>   t\projects\project-frontend"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I have already added the to windows path: c:\users~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt                  on SBT Console - grunt / node / npm commands are running. When I run SBT Run PortX command - then it shows grunt command now found issue!

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Intellij file "Grunt.scala" file in Project-Build folder and you can change file name "grunt" to "grunt.cmd" and it worked for me.